# Floating point addition in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

Why exactly does the latter case in Python doesn't yield the result `3.3`?

```
>>> 1.0 + 2.3
3.3
>>> 1.1 + 2.2
3.3000000000000003
```

It doesn't seem to make any sense to me what is going on here. What are the limitations here for the representation of the same result that you are getting through `1.0 + 2.3` but not through `1.1 + 2.2`?

Comment: Its a tough read, but this will help you understand what is going on: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Floating point numbers are, generally speaking, not exact representations of decimal numbers, but approximations.    To get exact representations of decimal numbers, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: @JasonSperske: I'd say that's recommended reading for anyone being able to rake in 5k in SO rep and wonder about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

And what you have stumbled upon is one of many idiosyncrasies:

```
>>> 1.1 + 1.1
2.2
>>> 1.1 + 2.3
3.4
>>> 1.1 + 2.2
3.3000000000000003
```

In fact, its a rare one, I've had a hard time finding other occurrences. Here's another weird one:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3
5.551115123125783e-17
```

Using Python's `decimal` class would give you better results.

Comment: or the decimal module

Comment: I gave you +1 but `numpy` is not a good solution here.  `numpy` still uses binary floats.  The `decimal` library would provide an exact solution here, as `decimal` operates exactly on decimal values.

Comment: I thought python just usually uses IEE754, and numpy probably, too. Could you give an example? Maybe you were thinking of e.g. `sympy.mpmath`.

Comment: +1 for `0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3` :)

Comment: @steveha @Benjamin You guys are right. It was my mistake, I thought numpy had more precision, but that turns out to be not entirely true. `Decimal` _is_ more precise, but its not all that precise either.

Comment: Well, `numpy` does offer several precisions of float, including `float64` and even `float96`.  So arguably it can be more precise.  But any binary float representation will be unable to exactly represent certain decimal fractions such as `0.1`.  (`0.5` is of course easy in binary float format.)  To put it another way: you already know that you cannot express `1/7` in any finite length decimal; no matter how many decimal places you write, you never reach the end of the fraction.  Well, binary fractions have the same problem with some decimal numbers.

Comment: 1.1*3 , 1.1*4, 1.1*2

Comment: How should I use `decimal` class? `Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.1) - Decimal(0.3)` gives `Decimal('2.775557561565156540423631668E-17')` output